# heap corruption detected after free

Tags: c

Why am I getting an error `Heap Corruption Detected` after normal block when I trying to free the string?
I read a name from a text file into a string (`nameS`), and after I used this string I try to "free" the memory

```
    char c;
    int phy = 0;
    int log = 1;
    char *nameS = (char *)malloc(log * sizeof(char));
    int id;

    checkallo(nameS);
    c = fgetc(f);

    while (c != ' ') {
        if (log == phy) {
            log = log * 2;
            nameS = (char *)realloc(nameS, log * sizeof(char));
            checkallo(nameS);
        }
        nameS[phy] = c;
        phy++;
        c = fgetc(f);
    }
    nameS[phy] = '\0';
    phy++;
    
    if (log > phy) {
        nameS = (char *)realloc(nameS, phy * sizeof(char));
        checkallo(nameS);
    }

    id = findInsId(InstTree, nameS);

    free(nameS); // <--- the problem

    return (id);
```

Comment: Likely some form of memory corruption. Which can be caused by any code prior to where an error is triggered. So we need to see a complete [mre].

Comment: You should check the return value of realloc by assigning to a temporary variable, realloc may return NULL but you assume it is always successful.

Comment: The code writes past the end of the allocated memory when the length of the string is a power of two.

Comment: Side-note: `c` needs to be declared an `int`, not a `char`, and you need to check for `EOF` (the former enables the latter, since `EOF` doesn't fit in a `char`).

Comment: @user3386109: Though I'd be mildly surprised if that actually caused a problem; a one-byte overwrite *usually* doesn't cause a major problem (that said, for a power-of-two allocation it would seem more likely to be an exact allocation).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, for a power-of-two allocation, it's likely to be exact (at least for size 16 and up), which is why even one character past the end is likely to be a problem.

Comment: @user3386109: Clearly gotta go with solely prime number allocations. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure there is enough space for the null terminator. For example if the user enters an one character word, `phy` and `log` will be `1` at the beginning of the second iteration, when the test `while (c != ' ')` stops the loop and `nameS[phy] = '\0';` writes beyond the end of the allocated array, causing undefined behavior (corrupting the heap as you observe).

Also note that `c` should have type `int` and you should handle `EOF`.

Note also that stopping on `' '` only is probably incorrect as words might be separated by other white space characters such as TAB or newline.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define checkallo(p)  do { if (!(p)) perror("allocation error"); } while (0)

int getInsId(FILE *f) {
    int c;
    int phy = 0;
    int log = 0;
    int id;
    char *nameS = malloc(log + 1);
    checkallo(nameS);

    while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF && !isspace(c)) {
        if (log == phy) {
            log = log * 2;
            nameS = realloc(nameS, log + 1);
            checkallo(nameS);
        }
        nameS[phy++] = c;
    }
    nameS[phy] = '\0';
    
    if (log > phy) {
        nameS = realloc(nameS, phy + 1);
        checkallo(nameS);
    }

    id = findInsId(InstTree, nameS);

    free(nameS);

    return id;
}
```

Comment: I believe you can replace `char *nameS = malloc(log + 1);` with just `char *nameS = NULL;` in the new code; `realloc` acts like `malloc` when passed `NULL`, and as is you're unconditionally `realloc`ing on the first time through the loop, to the exact same size you `malloc`ed. May as well simplify it.

Comment: `log = 0;` later `log = log * 2;`?

Comment: @i486: Somehow I read over that and neglected to notice the `+ 1` never made it back into `log` to ensure the doubling would have something to work with. This is what happens when you have insomnia all night before a flight in the morning.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: reallocating a null pointer indeed behaves like `malloc`, but in this particular context, I assumed the OP meant to read an empty string when the next byte is a space so an initial allocation of size `0+1` seems consistent.